# Symfony2 FOS login with role check

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, roles

I`m using the Symfony FOS userBundle, all works fine except for 1 thing.

I want on a user login to check if the user has a certain role. If not so the login must fail. Is there a way to do this? I searched half the internet but can`t find a solution.

```html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_PARENT:      ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_PARENT
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/            
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider                

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        mijn:
            pattern: ^/
            host: mijn.site
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        
        - { host: mijn.site, path: ^/gegevens, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { host: mijn.site, path: ^/, roles: ROLE_PARENT }
```

So the login may only succeed if the user has ROLE_PARENT. It must fail if it has ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_SUPERADMIN without ROLE_PARENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think FOSUserBundle provides anything as such, and you don't need one.
You can use a `Custom User Checkers`. Here is the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html) which explains it in detail. After you integrate `UserChecker` class, You can restrict someone to login under `checkPreAuth` method with your custom message.

A small code snippet :

```
public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!in_array('ROLE_PARENT', $user->getRoles()) {
        $ex = new DisabledException('Only Parent Users are allowed to login!');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

Works in my couple of projects.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot, This works!

Remember:

- You need at least Symfony 2.8 for this
- You need to define a user_checker for ALL your secured areas in your firewall

Comment: But, `Userchecker` is working for me in `Symfony 2.7`